# Why did the prisoners help Bruce?

Tags: analysis, the-dark-knight-rises

When Bruce is left broken and suffering in the Prison Pit, Bane explains that this is where he suffered and where Bruce will fully realize his failure with Gotham, and then be killed.

During his time there, the Doctor and his friend explain that Bane owns the prison, and their only duty is to keep him alive until Bane wants to kill him.  However, they seem to turn around, heal his back and start encouraging him to find the will and ability to climb out of the pit.

The question here is, *why*?

Why would they disobey Bane and help Bruce?

Comment: What did Bruce Wayne do once he got out?  Dropped a rope down for them to climb out.  Could be that simple.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet 'cept it's never shown that he did that - far as I'm aware.

Comment: Really? https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JkMl-ln6y2M - go to 1:35 of the video, which is right after he gets to the top and tell me what he does.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I stand corrected - shows that I should not try to comment on a movie I haven't seen in a few years.

Comment: I only remember it because I was thinking "Well, THAT is certainly convenient" when I saw the rope all ready to go.  Upon reflection, I suppose it's how supplies might get lowered into the pit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I see, it's still a prison and those prisoners who are under Bane's orders are trapped in the same way as Bruce Wayne was. There was no privilege which they enjoyed specifically more than him though.

Secondly Bruce was stuck there for a time that was time long enough to develop some camaraderie and seeing his passion and reaction to the way Gotham was destroyed in front of him could've appealed to their human side. It's often said prison is supposed to be creating a lot of retrospective thought processes for people who are imprisoned and I think they could've found a newer path after taking a look at Bruce Wayne and seeing him struggle against his wounds would've sparked a definite surge in them.

This third part I am not sure. Bane while he was in the pit as we see in the flashbacks fought with plenty of them protecting Talia. I think in a way he would've made enemies then. Since Bruce Wayne was against Bane. Enemy of my enemy theory could quite possibly have kicked in.

Answer (score 7):

I can see a possible selfish motivation in both the prisoners helping Bruce and Bane helping Talia and in a way shows a contrast between Bruce and Talia. Bane saves Talia in hope of her rescuing him alone, resulting in Ra's coming back to claim vengeance. Prisoners help Bruce when they become inspired by his strength yet at the same time hope he can both scale the wall and help them escape - which he actually does if you spot as soon as he defeats the pit he throws the abseil ropes down for them to pull themselves out. It shows that Bruce can inspire good and show mercy while Talia and Bane inspire hated and show vengeance.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the prisoners in there were no ordinary people. It would have taken them a lot to piss Bane in a way that instead of killing them he chose even a bigger punishment for them of putting in the pit and also for these prisoners death wouldn't have been a big deal just like for Batman. 
I am sure they were not afraid of Bane killing them as they were in even worse condition and would have preferred death anyway. Helping Batman would provide them a little sense of victory and hope which was very rare in that pit.
Also in the movie they had very high regard for the child who climbed the pit. So climbing the pit is a very big deal for them bigger than death.